# msg.sender in contract is empty

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs

I have the following deployment script

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(response.abi);
                var bytecode = response.bytecode;
                var options = {
                    from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,
                    gas: 1004000,
                    data: bytecode
                };

                console.log("Deploying the contract");

                contract.new(options
```

Everything seems to work also my contracts is deployed

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x12c135a0f44940f34379a063118a2a08143c3262

The problem is msg.sender is empty into the contracts 
and the function return 
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

this is set in the constructor in the Ownable OpenZeppelin contract
but deployed this way it return 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

My ABI https://pastebin.com/0XU4heNN

and bytecode https://pastebin.com/ThnDd1FC

The contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

import '../../../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';
import '../../../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol';

contract PropertyContract is ERC20Mintable, Ownable {

}
```

Comment: can you try `data: '0x' + bytecode`? I had a similar issue a while back. this fixed that.

Comment: I think this can help in older version - now 0x is in the bytecode https://pastebin.com/ThnDd1FC

Let me know if there must be two 0x0x.....

Comment: there need to be 1 `0x`

Comment: Yes, I know and that is why I dont add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fixed when I move to latest web3.js 1.0 
and instead of

```
contract.new()
```

I use now the deploy method from the version and everything seems to work fine

```
contract.deploy({
                        data:bytecode
                    })
                    .send({
                        from: web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress,
                        gas: 6004000,
                    })
                    .on('error', function (error) {
                        console.log("Error: " +error)
                    })
                    .on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash) {
                        console.log("Hash: " + transactionHash)
                    })
                    .on('receipt', function(receipt) {
                        console.log("Contract address: " + receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually send any bytecode, so a contract got created with no code. No calls to it will do anything useful.

```js
var options = {
  from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,
  gas: 1004000,
  data: "<bytecode here>", // <-- add this
};
```

Comment: When I add it my bytecode the contract fails to deploy 
because "out of gas", I try to increase it but when I increase I reach the maximum

Comment: Are you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Not without seeing your updated code. Ideally your smart contact code as well.